# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object Error PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

Hello I have been finding issues in code that was working fine before 
the $conn is giving error 
It is a simple insert with pdo in Php
I have a connection class which works fine through i perform following operations in my file

```
// query
try{


$sql="INSERT INTO vup_file(filename,path,category,sub_category,user_id,comment,language,duration)
VALUES (:filename,:path,:category,:subcategory,:user_id,:comment,:language,:duration)";
global $conn;
$query=$conn->prepare($sql);

$query->execute
(array(':filename'=>$filename,':path'=>$path,':category'=>$category,':subcategory'=>$subcategory,':user_id'=>$user_id,':comment'=>$comment,':language'=>$language,':duration'=>$duration));
echo 'Success';





}catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo 'ERROR OCCURED : '.$e->getMessage();
}
}
```

I am getting a error of  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 62 
I tried to make `$conn` but that just didn't work
how to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Did you define $conn? Please show us that place too

Comment: I have defined $conn over here itself and in the connection file and the connection code is working fine !

Comment: I am also using mysql_query from another file which I am using it in this file 
Is it because of that it is not working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you use mysql_query() in other file and it works fine.

It means you used mysql_connect().

It means you use procedure-style to connect to DB and create connection, but HERE you are trying to connect using OOP style and using connection created by mysql_connect().

It is impossible.

You need either to use OOP style to connect to DB:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
```

Or use procedure style to query DB instead of OOP-style:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO vup_file(filename,path,ca...
```

Procedure style is in past, now people mostly use OOP style, PDO objects.
PDO is the future, PDO is good.

And `mysql_*()` functions are in past, it is bad manner to write new code such way... Well it is explained here very well [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You global property $conn has not bee established correctly.

I would look back at your connection function and ensure that you have made a sucessful db connection.

Comment: My connection code is working fine !